# How can I add the roman page number of abstract and acknowledgement into table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

In a table of contents the page number first starts from the "Introduction" page. I want it to start from "Abstract" using `\section` not `\chapter`. How do I achieve that?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\section*{Abstract}
\section*{Acknowledgment}
\tableofcontents
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section{Introduction}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please do not post only fragments of code. The `sharelatex` tag is irrelevant here

Answer (score 6):

By default, `\section*` adds nothing to the ToC. You have to add it manually:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\section*{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract}
\clearpage

\section*{Acknowledgment}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}Acknowledgement}
\clearpage

\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Here are some additional things you need to note:

- `\pagenumbering` resets the page counter and changes the page display. However, in your example you've set it to `roman` and `arabic` *on the same page*. Only the last reference will be used as page numbering is only visible during page shipout.
- Adding section-specific content to the ToC is achieved using

  ```
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{<stuff>}
  ```

  where `<stuff>` includes your `\section*` title. You may decide to align this (unnumbered) title with the other (numbered) titles or not. `Abstract` is not aligned and flush left, while `Acknowledgement` is aligned with the other section titles.
- I've added `\clearpage` between every section so as to highlight the effect of the page numbering. This may differ from your actual implementation. Consider the effect of `\pagenumbering` though, as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Pagenumbering changes are only effective after a `\clearpage`. If the Table of Contents shouldn't be numbered with roman numbers, remove the second \clearpage before `\tableofcontents`. But `\section*` will not make an entry to the `ToC` at all.

Better use `\section{Abstract}` etc. and suppress the numbering with `\secnumdepth{-1}`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\section{Abstract}
\section{Acknowledgment}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % Reenable the numbering of sections etc. 
\clearpage % Now the table of contents
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

[image]